# How to do factorial using multiplication based on another function that has two parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I do factorial based on the multiply function? Thats what I have and the problem I'm running into is it gives me 0 instead of 5 != 120.

EDIT NEWEEST: how can I fix the double factorial to give me the right number?
if I do 5, it should give me 5!!= 15 but it gives me 12 why is that?

**SOURCE CODE**

```
def multiply(num1,num2):

    sum_of_multiplication= 0
    for i in range(num2):
        sum_of_multiplication = add(sum_of_multiplication,num1)
    return sum_of_multiplication



def factorial(num1):
    factorial_num = num1
    for i in range(1,num1):
        num1 = multiply(factorial_num,num1)
        print(factorial_num)
    print(str(num1) + "!= " + str(factorial_num))



 def double_factorial(num1):
    double_factorial_num = 2
    for i in range(1,num1-2):
        double_factorial_num = multiply(double_factorial_num, i)
        print(double_factorial_num)
    print(str(num1) + "!!= " + str(double_factorial_num))

double_factorial = double_factorial(int(input("please enter your intger:")))
```

Comment: You never use `i`: `num1 = multiply(factorial_num,num1)` should read `factorial_num = multiply(factorial_num, i)`

Comment: `factorial_num` should probably be initialized to 1. That would give you the right answer for 1! and 0!.

Comment: Currently , I'm getting the input number as my result, not zero. I am also going to guess that you did not read the printout which shows that you never update the result.

Comment: No it worked thanks and if I want to do a double factorial how would I do that? will I need another loop or how would it work?

Comment: What is a double factorial?

Comment: Also, please fix your question to give the actual output. The desired output is indeed `5 != 120`, but none of the intermediate or final results are zero.

Comment: it goes by two nubmers so 6*4*2 instead of 6*5*4*3*2*1 ...

Comment: @MadPhysicist See [Double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). Yes, it's annoying notation, but it's entrenched, so there's nothing we can do about it. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring help me figure it please I've wasted 1.5 hours on it.

Comment: @PM2Ring  will reupload what I have

Comment: @IbrahimAyyoub You shouldn't change your question like that. In the beginning you asked about factorial, so you shouldn't change it to ask about double factorial instead. However, to do a double factorial you need to count by 2. I suggest using a range like `range(num1, 0, -2)`.

Comment: Please ask a separate question about double factorial. Also, fix the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are including 0 in your multiplication. In the range function (in the factorial function), put `1` as the first parameter to make it look like `range(1,num1)`. This way the multiplication will start at `1`, not `0`.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm confused

Comment: The range function you used starts from 0 (`range(num1)`) and goes upwards. When you multiply by zero you get zero. Therefore, you should start from 1, not 0, for your factorial function to work.

Comment: Its not working and I can only use one paramter as the factorial functoin since it only takes a single paramter I reuploaded the function for factorial is there any mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure how people are upvoting the question? its not fixing anything?

Comment: Pretty sure you want `range(1, num1 + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `factorial()` is slightly off due to a `range()` issue, which is an easy mistake to make but you should be able to fix it quickly by reviewing the documentation for `range()`.  However, your `double_factorial()` function has no hope of success as you fail to deal with a key issue up front, the parity (odd or even) of the number:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def multiply(a, b):

    my_sum = 0

    for _ in range(b):
        my_sum = add(my_sum, a)

    return my_sum

def factorial(number):
    product = 1

    for multiplicand in range(2, number + 1):
        product = multiply(product, multiplicand)

    print(str(number) + "!", "=", product)

def double_factorial(number):
    parity = number % 2 + 2  # start at 2 or 3

    product = 1

    for multiplicand in range(parity, number + 1, 2):
        product = multiply(product, multiplicand)

    print(str(number) + "!!", "=", product)

number = int(input("please enter your integer: "))

factorial(number)

double_factorial(number)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
please enter your integer: 5
5! = 120
5!! = 15
>
```